# Are the critical points of a vector 2 norm the same as the norm square?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Is the set of critical points of $\|Ax\|_2^2$ subject to $\|Bx\|_2^2 = 1$ the same set as the set of critical points of $\|Ax\|_2$ subject to $\|Bx\|_2 = 1$? Clearly the constraint conditions are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not quite the same. Define the norm function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. $f(x)=||x||$. 
$f(x)=\sqrt{x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2+...x_{n}^2}$. Note that the critical points of a $C^1$ function ($f$ and $f'$ are continuous), are when $f'=0$. We can compute the derivative and arrive at $f'=\frac{1}{2}(x_{1}^2+...+x_{n}^2)^{-1/2}(2x_{1}+...+2x_{n})$. This is not quite the same as $f^2$ which is $||x||^2=x_{1}^2+..+x_{n}^2$